# Does it make sense to set up mediaPlayer to run in a separate thread in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, media-player

I've recently begun experimenting with a mediaPlayer instance in my Android app.  I implemented a couple different beeps for feedback to the user.  Now, when I implemented an audioTrack (for a completely different purpose), I discovered that it pretty much sets itself up as a separate thread automatically (as far as I can tell).  It certainly appears as a separate thread when I run my code in the debugger:
     Thread [<17> AudioTrackThread] (Running)

My question is: Does mediaPlayer do something similar?  My first guess is that it does not -- or I would see thread descriptions in the debugger, right??

Anyway, now I've got to questions:
1)  Can I set up my mediaPlayers as separate threads and still have them work right?
2)  Does it make sense even to try it?

Thanks,
R.

Comment: For what you are going with multiple sounds, you might want to look at SoundPool.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MediaPlayer` will still work like its supposed to in a thread, I've done that before so I could still do everything asynchronously without using the callbacks.  I wouldn't spawn more than one of them though they use a lot of resources.